# ServiceNOW publish article through API

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I managed to get add an article to the knowledge base in ServiceNow using the API. However, the added article is always in draft.

Is there a way to publish an article with the API?

It is fine to do this in a separate API call if need.

Moreover, I already tried to update the records (PUT request) in the table 'kb_knowledge':
`{"active":"true","published":"2023-07-18","workflow_state":"Published"}`